# ROW_NUMBER() in H2 not working

Tags: sql, database, h2

I am trying to rank duplicates rows in H2. Since H2 does not support window functions like `RANK()`. I am trying to use `Row_Number()` but it not working it throws error saying syntax error. Please guide what is the problem. I am new to SQL and H2 database.

```
Insert into t2(c1, c2, c3, rank1, rank2) 
   select 
      c1, c2, c3,
      ROW_NUMBER OVER(partition by c1 order by c3) as rank1,
      ROW_NUMBER OVER(partition by c2 order by c3) as rank2
from t1
```

Please guide. Thanks in advance. How do I resolve above syntax error? It says ; ) expected. Also please let me know good workaround to find rank in H2 database.

Comment: You said it yourself: "*Since H2 does not support window functions*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace ROW_NUMBER() with subqueries with COUNT(). The only issue is that they will generate same ranks for equal `C3` fields.

```
   select 
      c1, c2, c3,

      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 as T3 WHERE T3.C1=T1.C1 AND T3.C3<=T1.C3 ) as rank1,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 as T3 WHERE T3.C2=T1.C2 AND T3.C3<=T1.C3 ) as rank2
   from t1
```

Answer (score 1):

A note for anyone finding this many years after it was answered - H2 **did** eventually add support for window functions in early 2019, starting with version 1.4.198 ([release notes](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/releases/tag/version-1.4.198)). Check your H2 version to see if you can take advantage!